# didSelectRowAtIndexPath method does not load new View in iOS app code is inside

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have my first and normal view controller with a `UITableView` in it. The items that need to be displayed in those rows work perfectly.

Now comes the issue, if the user selects a row, I want a new view opened.
This view is called `SecondViewController`. so I have the `.h`, `.m` and `.xib` file named that way and it is of the `UIViewController` class.

I am using a `CustomCell` for the tableview could this be the issue?

I have `#imported` everything normally, and this is the code I am using in the method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    SecondViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];

}
```

What on earth am I doing wrong? I have been looking at questions here for hours but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: "and it is of the UIView class" - "UIViewController", you mean? If it really is a subclass of UIView, that's not good.

Comment: Is the current view controller actually in a nav controller? In other words, is `self.navigationController` non-nil?

Comment: @H2CO3 I've had UITableView's inside UIView's before - it's not fun, and you have to be careful, but it does work. Some design patterns require it.

Comment: Could you add a breakpoint to make sure that method gets called?

Comment: @Undo Imagine that I've done that too before. Clearly, you didn't understand my point.

Comment: Yea that is correct, when I created the new viewcontroller I chose the viewcontroller class, let me edit that :p

Comment: @H2CO3 Yes, I understand your point. It's bad code design, and shouldn't really be done.

Comment: I found what is in the method here on stackoverflow should I use something else? :p

Comment: @Undo No. That's not my point. If `SecondViewController` is a subclass of `UIView` and not `UIViewController`, as OP affirms, then it cannot possibly be pushed to another view controller.

Comment: But it is UIViewController, my bad

Comment: What does the selection of a tableview row have anything to do with a viewcontroller?  Does secondViewController get reference to tableview's index path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that self.navigationController is not nil?

Try to log it, From your code your problem is probably that, your self.navigationController is nil.

This class is pushed from another or are you starting the navigation in this class? If you are starting it in this class, this is your issue, you need to call the navigation that you created and not the one that is supposed to be with your viewcontroller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i'll try to figure this is out. I am quite new to iPhone development as you might have noticed :)

Comment: If you need any help, just ask, lets solve your problem together.

Comment: Ok thank you! So you say that my navigationcontroller may not be nill, now where make it so it is not nill? I think I really missed a step somewhere in my code

Comment: Your navigation is nil? How are you initialising it ? How you add this view controller that must push the other?

Comment: I'll look into navigation controller and how to use it, I simply copy pasted that whole method that I posted here and adapted the viewcontroller, i'll comment here again if I still can't figure it out :)

Comment: But Actually I don't think I even need a navigation controller since the user has to be directed to a new screen when he/she selects a row or am I mistaking?

Comment: no, you are right, you probably can use `presentViewController:animated:completion:` and it will do the job for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time mate!
I just restarted with using a navigationcontroller as it should be done! So now it all runs smooth :D